# python tkinter Button command doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

okok,i tried making a button that'd close the window,but it doesn't work,and now I am once again asking for your python support...

```
schaltf1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="EXIT", width=20, command=root.destroy()) #command=root.destroy())
schaltf1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Thats the source code,maybe you could help me?
That'd be very nice, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
command = root.destroy
```

you pass the function itself without calling it.

So your source code should be:

```
schaltf1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="EXIT", width=20, command=root.destroy)
```